# Rewrite double url issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying several different combinations for resolving the following URL. I just can't get it to redirect where I need it to.

```
https://www.oldsite.com/http://www.oldsite.com/
```

needs to redirect to

```
https://www.newsite.com/
```

I can't find the right combination to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is it that you are getting that type of URL to begin with?

Comment: It showed up in Google analytics as a 404.

Comment: Is that one URL or did you mean `https://www.oldsite.com/` and `http://www.oldsite.com/`

Comment: That is how it was listed in Google.